# Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to closure result type 'CGPoint'

Tags: swift

Please consider following:

```
struct Entry {
    let points: [CGPoint]

    func squeezePoints(_ multiplier: CGFloat) -> [CGPoint]{
        return points.map{$0.x * multiplier}
    }
}
```

Code not compile because of error: `Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to closure result type 'CGPoint'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to map to a `CGFloat`, but declared the return type of your function as `[CGPoint]`. If you want to multiply the x coordinate of each point, modify your function to map to a `CGPoint` and keep the `y` unmodified.

```
func squeezePoints(_ multiplier: CGFloat) -> [CGPoint]{
    return points.map{CGPoint(x: $0.x * multiplier, y: $0.y)}
}
```

Comment: points is already [CGPoint], i only modify each of it X values.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You're not modifying the X value. You're returning the multiplied X value (and only the X value, not the point).

Comment: why, i mapping array with modifying one of its value, other should remain unchanged.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban map it is not a mutating method. You would need to iterate the array indices and modify each element of your array

Comment: yes, but im not trying to mutate points array but instead return it with modifying one of its values..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban check my updated answer, modified it to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: ok, its work, but i still don't understand why my approach not work. As i said, i modify one of initial array values, therefore, i return new points array (which is [CGPoint])

Comment: `map` does not modify anything, it transforms things